# Direct proof: $f$ is continuous $\implies$ preimage is closed

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Let be $f:M\to N$ a continuous function where $M\subseteq X$. Then we know that every closed subset $S\subseteq N$ has a preimage $f^{-1}(S)$ such that there exists a closed set $Q\subseteq X$ with $f^{-1}(S)=Q\cap M$.

---

In the equivalent statement which is about *open* sets we are able to construct an *open* set $Q$ and by that we prove the statement regarding *open* sets. Now, I am wondering if it is also possible to show the above statement *directly* by constructing a closed set $Q$ (no use of contraposition or the equivalent statement with *open* sets)?

Comment: What would be the point in that? A closed set is defined as a set, for which the conjugate set is open. Hence, it is very direct to prove facts about closed sets by proving facts about open sets.

Comment: @Benjamin, if you work with that definition you are right. However, the point is that I am curious if it is possible to construct such a closed set $Q$ instead of only proving its existence.